# Overwrite versions in ear (Maven)

Tags: java, maven, ear, parent-pom

We have a given ear `company-ear` in our Nexus. Now I want to build the same ear, but overwrite the version of jar `A` with `7.0.0` and of jar `B` with `1.2.3`.

How can I achieve that? My initial idea was to set the `company-ear`-pom as parent pom and add the dependencies `A` and `B` in the correct version. But this does not overwrite the specified versions.

Any other idea?

EDIT: Some explanation of the background: A central group in our company builds `company-ear`, gathering jars from many separate groups. Now if a group wants to test their newest jars, they copy the `company-ear` and exchange their jars with the newest versions. This is a tedious process and I would like to improve it.

Comment: Please post some relevant pom.xml

Comment: Do you not have the original pom used to build the EAR?

Comment: If you need to have a different version in the EAR you need to create the EAR new with different versions of modules means you need to build a new version of the EAR ...

Comment: @SteveC: I can download or reference the pom from Nexus.

Comment: @khmarbaise: The ear is in Nexus, but I cannot change the project that created it. I could copy&paste the pom from Nexus and then change the groupId etc. and the versions, but I look for a more generic approach.

Comment: You can use maven-assembly-plugin and repackage things...if you need but I think the better aproach is to fix the original project and release a new version of the EAR...

Comment: @khmarbaise Edited to explain the background.

Comment: Does the original pom generate it's own `application.xml` file? Does the EAR contain any additional server dependent deployment descriptors?